# Book about kids riding a flying snake in a magical realm

Tags: identification-request

I read an English-language novel in the mid-2000s about a group of 2 or 3 kids, probably siblings and/or cousins. I think they travel from out of town to a relative's home in the southern United States. They wander through a swamp or bayou and find some sort of entrance to a magical realm. Like Narnia, the realm is controlled by the bad guys, and the kids are savior figures who get chased around. Unfortunately that's all I remember, except for the fact that there's a giant flying/gliding snake that the kids ride to travel from the realm's surface to the bottom of a huge, open underworld.

The book was written for a juvenile or young adult audience. I haven't found any matches with search terms like "fiction magic giant flying snake".